# Путь до библиотек Qt

Tags: qt, ubuntu, cmake, makefile

Установил Qt с официального инсталятора на Ubuntu. Лежит отдельной папкой в opt.
Необходимо помочь cmake / make найти путь до его библиотек. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: В переменной окружения path прописать пути до *.a и *.so файлов qtsdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Необходимо помочь cmake / make найти путь до его библиотек. Как правильно это сделать?

Подразумевая, что Qt в `CMakeLists.txt` ищется «обычным» способом:

```
find_package ( Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED )
```

То `find_package` ищет файл `Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake` (вообще говоря вместе с несколькими другими). Для поиска используется значительное количество каталогов порядок которых описан в [документации](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html). Таким образом есть много способ задать пордок поиска, но одним из первых просматривается каталоги вида `${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib/cmake/`.

т.е. самым простым способом надёжно задать директорию поиска будет установить `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`; подразумевая, что Qt куда-то в `/opt/qt-upstream`, а `*.cmake`-файлы лежат в `/opt/qt-upstream/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake`, это будет выглдеть примерно так: например так:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/qt-upstream
```

**Замечания:**

- Вообще говоря, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` — список префиксов, разделяемый точкой запятой.
- Можно задать директории поиска и другими способами. см. доки.